# Read array of Objects of WSDL file using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am new to Web Services. I have requirement to read an Array of Invoices Objects from SOAP response using PHP soapClient function. Below is my SOAP response:

```
<Soap:Envelope xmlns:Soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Soap:Body>
      <InvoiceQuery_Result xmlns="urn:web">
         <xmlInvoice>
            <Header xmlns="urn:Invoice">
               <Cust_No>12345</Cust_No>               
               <Lines>
                  <Line_No>10000</Line_No>                  
                  <LotSerial>
                     <Qty>1</Qty>
                     <Serial>12345-001</Serial>
                  </LotSerial>
               </Lines>               
            </Header>
            <Header xmlns="urn:Invoice">
               <Cust_No>12346</Cust_No>               
               <Lines>
                  <Line_No>10001</Line_No>                  
                  <LotSerial>
                     <Qty>2</Qty>
                     <Serial>12345-002</Serial>
                  </LotSerial>
               </Lines>               
            </Header>
            <Header xmlns="urn:Invoice">
               <Cust_No>12347</Cust_No>               
               <Lines>
                  <Line_No>10002</Line_No>                  
                  <LotSerial>
                     <Qty>4</Qty>
                     <Serial>12345-003</Serial>
                  </LotSerial>
               </Lines>               
            </Header>
         </xmlInvoice>
      </InvoiceQuery_Result>
   </Soap:Body>
</Soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What is the question?